# ParseExact Argument Error Despite Working Output

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to import a CSV with column "RequestDate" which contains dates and convert that to datetime. To simplify the test, the only date entered in the CSV is 5/26/2021.

The CSV is saved to $GetCSV.

When I run the following code, I get a "String was not recognized as valid datetime error":

```
$GetCSV | ForEach-Object { $_.RequestDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.RequestDate, 'M/dd/yyyy', $null) }
```

However If I changed the date in the CSV to 10/26/2021, the code doesn't throw out any errors, even if the format in ParseExact remains 'M/dd/yyyy
'.

Is the formatting in ParseExact incorrect or is this the problem with the CSV source? How could I resolve it?

Comment: I don't get that error on a quick test. Did you type your data or is it extracted from file metadata? Date strings obtained from Shell.Application methods may contain "inivisible" (non-printing) formatting & record-seperator characters that will throw this error.

Comment: The data was sent to me via CSV from a vendor. However I am now trying it again (after many attempts) and it is working... and I'm not sure why.